# Saving binary data with cocoa

Tags: cocoa, binary

I have some code that executes the command `unzip -p myzip.zip picture.png` that prints out the "binary" data of picture.png. If it's saved with the correct extension, upon opening it it gives an error saying the file is corrupt. So my question is what is the proper way to write this data to a file using cocoa? Right now Im just using `[data writeToFile:@"/picture.png" atomically:NO];`. I know binary is supposed to be 1's and 0's but it gives "binary" code like this:

```
?VaE?.?_QA?J+G:'GD?{C??!? ??٬?d?V ?E?e???8^?t?-P?ʍ?psq???N?S:????,l^&?,_."? ??!a?Y`?,?-??.I ?ILD]?Ҙ佊??????????FLߊŜ?D??Y%?@O?#/??#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading through the extremely long `man` page for the 3rd time, I found out a better way to accomplish it, using the `-d` argument.

Answer (score 1):

All data is saved in 0s and 1s (at this time of writing). When you print the file to the display it gives the ASCII characters with the saved values.

When saving a file as 'binary' this basically means that newlines are not converted. The PNG is saved correctly, although 'unzip' may unzip it wrong, the zip is corrupted or the png in the zip is corrupted.

---

This is correct Cocoa:

```
[data writeToFile:@"/picture.png" atomically:YES];
```

atomically:YES is recommended.

---

The problem with your code might be that the NSData doesn't contain valid PNG data, but only raw image data, GIF data, JPEG data or another kind of non-png data.